# Why do I get an error when calling front() on boost::ptr_list?

Tags: c++

I have got a virtual class `basic_action`. Class `sippeers` inherits class `basic_action`. To store instances of `sippeers` classes I'm using `boost::ptr_list`. Here's code example:

```
boost::ptr_list<basic_action> ActionsList;
sippeers spclass;
ActionsList.push_back(&spclass);
basic_action *sp = ActionsList.front();
```

Here I create an instance of `prt_list` with pointers to instances of my `basic_action` classes.
Next I make new instance of my `sippeers` class.
Next I insert pointer to `sippeers` class into `ptr_list`.

The last string fails.

> Cannot convert from 'basic_action' to
>   'basic_action *'.

But there IS a `basic_action *` inside, not `basic_action`!

Comment: This is unrelated to your question, but boost pointer containers take ownership of the objects you put into them. You don't want to put a stack allocated object into a ptr_list.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`boost::ptr_list::front()` returns a reference to the templated type, not a pointer.

So in this case it's returning a `basic_action&`.

See the documentation [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/ptr_container/doc/ptr_sequence_adapter.html) for `ptr_sequence_adapter`, from which `ptr_list` is derived.

So your code should read:

```
boost::ptr_list<basic_action> ActionsList;
sippeers spclass;
ActionsList.push_back(&spclass);
basic_action &sp = ActionsList.front();
```

Comment: boost::ptr_list::front() returns a reference. The last line should be: basic_action& sp = ActionsList.front();

Comment: @Ferruccio Thanks - caught my typo and edited about 7 mins ago. :)

Answer (score 2):

ptr_list::front() returns a reference to the first object in the list.
If basic_action was a concrete type you could both of the following.

```
// 1
basic_action& sp = ActionsList.front();

// 2
basic_action sp = ActionsList.front();
```

#1 would make sp a reference to the first object in the list. In other words, any changes you made through sp would also change the first object in the list.

#2 would instantiate a new basic_action object and copy the contents of the first object in the list into this new object. Any changes to it would not affect the first item in the list.

If basic_action is an abstract class option #2 is no longer available to you because you cannot instantiate abstract class objects.

also, you shouldn't put stack allocated objects into a boost pointer container. Bad things will happen when the ptr_list goes out of scope and tries to delete all the objects it contains. Instead do something like:

```
boost::ptr_list<basic_action> ActionsList;
ActionsList.push_back(new sippeers);
basic_action& sp = ActionsList.front();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the [header](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/ptr_container/doc/ptr_sequence_adapter.html) then you will see that:

```
template
<
    class T,
    class VoidPtrSeq,
    class CloneAllocator = heap_clone_allocator
>
class ptr_sequence_adapter
{
public: // construct/copy/destroy
    template< class InputIterator >
    assign( InputIterator first, InputIterator last );
    template< class InputRange >
    assign( const InputRange& e );

public: // element access
    T&        front();
```

(Note; ptr_list directly inherits from ptr_sequence_adapter) So you are getting the type, not a reference to the type; it does an automatic dereference for you:

```
basic_action sp = ActionsList.front();
```

is correct.

Comment: I've tried to use this kind of code, but Visual Studio generates error: error C2259: 'basic_action' : cannot instantiate abstract class.

Comment: @CagoBHuK: that's because it's not correct. You're lucky you get another compiler error and not weird behaviour from unintentional slicing.

Comment: @CagoBHuK: the problem is that boost::ptr_list::front() returns a reference. You can assign it to a reference (basic_action& sp = ...) but without the reference it will try to copy the referenced object to a new basic_action object (which it can't instantiate because it's an abstract type)